# PowerShell About files, format to print

Tags: powershell

I want to print the "about" files of `PowerShell` (official  online [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847856.aspx)). the text does not wrap, but lines are separated manually. It's hard work to deal with it.

There any source where data appears in the design "normal" for Print / Web?

Comment: Are you trying to print the ones from the web or the ones in PowerShell? Depending on the source it changes the answer. Also not sure what you mean by _text does not wrap, but lines are separated manually_. I'm not sure I'm clear what you are doing.

Comment: Files are the same on both the computer and the Internet - a line width "fixed", the tables were made by Indents text (spaces) which interferes with a non fixed-wdith font, and ect.

Comment: So do you not care where you get the data as long as the lines are continuous as they would be in a proper document?